# Concatenation of a string and a regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to concatenate a regex and a string and want to compare the resultant string with another string.How can I do that in java?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegexMatching {


public static void main(String aaa[])
{
    String testStr="anjaneyPANDEY";

    String regEx = "([A-Z])";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);

    String st="anjaney"+regEx;
    if(testStr.matches(st))
        System.out.println("YES");
    else System.out.println("NO");
}
}
```

Comment: add a + or a * at the end of your regex, depending on what you want. have you read about greedy and non-greedy regex patterns yet?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you forgot to add `+` in your regex to let it match one or more uppercase character. You should use `[A-Z]+` since `matches` checks if entire string can be matched with regex.

Also you should use created `Matcher` instance instead of `testStr.matches(st)` to not recompile every time your pattern. So your code can look like

```
String regEx = "([A-Z]+)";
String st = "anjaney" + regEx;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(st);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);

if (matcher.matches())
    System.out.println("YES");
else
    System.out.println("NO");
```

This approach is OK if you know that string you want to combine with regex doesn't have any regex metacharacters like `(` `*` `+` and so on.
But if you are not sure about it then you need to create escape such metacharacters. In that case you can use `Pattern.quote()` method. So instead of

```
String st = "anjaney" + regEx;
```

you can use

```
String st = Pattern.quote("anjaney") + regEx;
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
    String testStr = "anjaneyPANDEY";

    String regEx = "([A-Z])+";

    String st = "anjaney" + regEx;


    if (testStr.matches(st)) {
        System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
```